# Mathematical Induction Year 12 math question

Tags: induction

Prove by mathematical induction that $n$ can be written as an expression of multiples of $4$ and $5$, $n\geq12$

I understand the initial case where $n = 12$
$$
12 = 4\cdot 3 + 5\cdot 0
$$
which is a multiple of $4$ and $5$

Assumption: let $n = k$ so
$$
k = 4x + 5y
$$
Rearranging the equation you get: $4x = k - 5y$

Prove for $n = k+1$

RTP: $k+1 = 4(x-1) + 5(y+1)$
BUT you can also have the fact of:
$k+1 = 4(x+4)$ - because it can go back to being a string of $4$s

Is this the right track?? then you look at the RHS of both cases

Comment: $P(12)$: $12=4\times 3+5\times 0$. Assume $n$ can be written as $4n_1+5n_2$, then $n+1$ can be written as $5(n_2+1)+4(n_1-1)$, where $n,n_1,n_2\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Yes I am familiar with mathematical induction, from looking at some solutions, i came up with the basic equation for the problems: 5x + 4y, but im not sure where to start my test case

Comment: Is $17 = 4\cdot (-2) + 5 \cdot 5$ allowed, or are you looking for a sum *non-negative* multiples of $4$ and $5$?

Answer (score 1):

This is my **solution** for your question

So we have

$12=4\times 3$,

$13=4\times 2 +5$,

$14=4 + 5\times 2$,

$15=5 \times 3$,

$16= 4 \times 4$.

You can see that if we have a 4 and we want to increase by 1 then we change one 1 by one 5. And if we don't have one 4, then by induction from 15, we must have at least $3\times 5$, so we swap 3 number 5s for 4 number 4s. So $4\times 4 - 5\times 3 =1$

Q.E.D

Comment: Don't say "“you really need to consider posting more carefully revised contents”" in an answer. If it is a good question then answer it. If the question needs to be improved then leave a comment and/or vote on it. But *“it is a bad question but I'll answer it anyway”* leaves a wrong impression, and even can encourage more bad questions.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. I am an inexperienced newbie too so my apologize for it.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time using this website I’m not sure what I’m supposed to include and what not. I apologise for any confusions guys.

Answer (score 1):

Base case:

$$12=4\cdot 3+5\cdot0$$

Inductive steps:

- if $n$ is a linear combination of $4$ and $5$, so is $n+5$ (obvious);
- if $n$ is a linear combination of $4$ and $5$, so is $n+4$ (obvious);
- if $n$ is a linear combination of $4$ and $5$, so is $n+3$ (because $3=5\cdot3-4\cdot3$);
- if $n$ is a linear combination of $4$ and $5$, so is $n+2$ (because $2=5\cdot2-4\cdot2$);
- if $n$ is a linear combination of $4$ and $5$, so is $n+1$ (because $1=5-4$).

Hence if true for $n$, then true for $n,n+1,\cdots n+5,n+5+1,n+5+2,\cdots n+5+5,\cdots$ and finally true for all $n\ge 12$.

Note: as we never deduct multiples of $4$ with a coefficient higher than $3$, the coefficients are guaranteed to remain non-negative. This condition was left implicit in the inductive steps, for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Induction is used to prove statements about infinitely many things.

For induction, you need $3$ steps.

1) Check if the statement you are about to prove is true for some small values of $n$

2) Assume that  the statement is true for some value of $n$ say $k$

3) USING 2) prove that the statement is true for $k+1$.

One usually says the analogy of dominoes. Imagine an infinitely long chain of dominoes standing in a row. You would like to show that "all of them will fall". To do so you show that whenever one falls it will tilt the next one (this is the essence of step 3). And you show that the first (or one in the beginning will fall) this is the essence of step 1).

1) check for some small values of $n$ say $n=13$, in this case

$$
2\cdot 4+1\cdot 5 =13
$$

Nice!

2) assume that the statement is true for some $n=k$ where $k\ge 14$ so you say that you are sure that the equation
$$
k= a\cdot 4+b\cdot 5
$$
has integer solutions for $a$ and $b$

I leave the rest for you

Hope this helped

---

EDIT after some comments and edit in the question

Nice! You are on the right track!

Actually nothing in the question says that your $x$ and $y$ has to be positive so you are basically done!

Comment: yes i understand this process well, but when doing step 3, how do i implement my assumption into the inductive step? my assumption is k = 4x + 5y, then proving for n = k+1

Comment: the disturbing part is the $+1$ right? just another hint: try to add this to your question, it will be recieved a lot better

Comment: @warpax edit your question so it contains everything you have tried, all progress so far and it won't get so many downvotes also it will be easier to help, when you done that I can help

Comment: yep i edited my case

Answer (score 0):

You have assumed that $k=4x+5y$ and we want to show that $k+1 = 4m+5n$

We can say that \begin{align}k+1&=(4x+5y)+1\\
&=(4x+5y)+(5-4)\\
&=4(x-1)+5(y+1)\end{align}

so now we can say that $m=x-1$ and $n=y+1$ which are both integers and we have proved the inductive step

Comment: Thankyou very much!! this makes alot of sense :)